# Loading json from multiple files in one folder and putting them into one dicitionary (or list)

Tags: python, json

I have multiple text files that have this inside them(with diferent values):

```
{"abandon": {"R1F2V0CQAYJOZZ": 2, "R3NUFWQ9SPGVJO": 1}, "abduct": {"R1F2V0CQAYJOZZ": 1, "R3376OQSHCTV1A": 1, "R14BW4EQZNVKKG": 1, "R233CMES8RCOCU": 1},
```

If i format it online it becomes like this:

```
   "abandon":{
      "R1F2V0CQAYJOZZ":2,
      "R3NUFWQ9SPGVJO":1
   },
   "abduct":{
      "R1F2V0CQAYJOZZ":1,
      "R3376OQSHCTV1A":1,
      "R14BW4EQZNVKKG":1,
      "R233CMES8RCOCU":1
   },
```

What this JSON mean is:

```
"word":{
   "Document name":"value"
},
```

But there are repeated words in diferent files.
What i want to do is:
Read all files and store everything in one dictionary, but:

1. If the "word" exists in the dictionary check if the "document" is there;
2. If the "document exists", then increment the "value", else put the document there and the "value = 1"
3. If the "word" doesnt exist, store the "word", "document" and "value = 1"

EDIT:

So imagine this 2 files:

File1.txt = {"abandon": {"doc1": 2, "doc2": 1}, "abduct": {"doc1": 1, "doc2": 1, "doc8": 1},

File1.txt = {"abandon": {"doc1": 1, "doc3": 1}, "abduct": {"doc5": 1, "doc8": 1},

I want my dictionary to end like this:

```
{"abandon": {"doc1": 3, "doc2": 1, "doc3": 1}, "abduct": {"doc1": 1, "doc2": 1, "doc5": 1, "doc8": 2},
```

EDIT2:
it can also be a nested List

Comment: Can you include one more file sample and the expected output for the two files combined?

Comment: edited, is it more clear now? this is only an example with 2 files, there are multiple files

Comment: You can use the json library to convert the input to dictionaries. To read all files, you can use os.listdir(folder) and it'll give you all the file and folder names in the specified folder.

Comment: @ZShadow01 but i dont want to create a dictionary for each file, i want all files in the same dictionary

Comment: What's the result if "doc1":2 and "doc1:3" in two files?  You say "increment", but do you really want "doc1":5 in the merged dictionary?

Comment: @ObamaVEVO you can merge the dictionaries

Comment: But that is not efficient, cause each dictionary is going to take a lot of disk memory, what i am doing is a SPIMI approach

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Consider a simplified problem of two dictionaries without any distractions. One you've solved that on your own, add in the other parts.

Comment: @MarkTolonen the "2" and "3" is the number of occurences from that word in the document, so in the doc1 the word is going to be there 5 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
import os
import json

files = [f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith(".txt")]
result = dict()

for file in files:
    d = json.load(open(file))
    for word in d:
        if word not in result:
            result[word] = dict()
        for doc in d[word]:
            if doc not in result[word]:
                result[word][doc] = d[word][doc]
            else:
                result[word][doc] += d[word][doc]

>>> result
{'abandon': {'doc1': 3, 'doc2': 1, 'doc3': 1},
 'abduct': {'doc1': 1, 'doc2': 1, 'doc8': 2, 'doc5': 1}}
```

Input files:

file1.txt:

```
{"abandon": {"doc1": 2, "doc2": 1}, "abduct": {"doc1": 1, "doc2": 1, "doc8": 1}}
```

file2.txt:

```
{"abandon": {"doc1": 1, "doc3": 1}, "abduct": {"doc5": 1, "doc8": 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

files = ["input", "list", "of", "files"]
outDict = {}
for file in files:  # iterate over the files
    with open(file) as fn:
        newDict = json.load(fn)
    for word in newDict:  # iterate over each word from the file
        inWord = newDict[word]
        outWord = outDict.get(word, {})  # returns an empty dict if word isn't already in the output dictionary
        for docName in inWord:  # iterate over each document name from the file
            value = outWord.get(docName, 0)  # returns 0 if the document name isn't already in the output dictionary
            value += 1  # increment the value
            outWord[docName] = value  # update the output dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

It's straight-forward to merge using `.setdefault`:

```py
import json
import glob

merged = {}

for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):  # match *.txt files in current directory

    with open(file) as f:
        in_dict = json.load(f)

        for word, docs in in_dict.items():
            for doc, value in docs.items():
                merged.setdefault(word,{})       # create word with empty dict value if it doesn't exist
                merged[word].setdefault(doc, 0)  # create value of 0 for document if it doesn't exist
                merged[word][doc] += value       # add the doc's value.

print(json.dumps(merged,indent=2))
```

Or using `defaultdict`.  The parameter to defaultdict must be a function that returns the default value, hence the lambda that returns a default integer dictionary:

```py
import json
import glob
from collections import defaultdict

merged = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):  # match *.txt files in current directory

    with open(file) as f:
        in_dict = json.load(f)

        for word, docs in in_dict.items():
            for doc,value in docs.items():
                merged[word][doc] += value       # add the doc's value.

print(json.dumps(merged,indent=2))
```